# Sequelize: Get a specific column with .findAll and include

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to get only a specific field from 1 to many relationship object.

Below is my code:

```
 db.User.findAll({
            where: {
                id: ids
            },
            include: [{
                model: db.Common,
                as: 'color',
                through: {
                    attributes: ['color']
                }
            }]
        }).then((users) => {
```

User has a 1-m association with the `Common` table.  I would like only the `color` field returned as `color` with the `User` object  i.e. the returned object in an array would like:

```
 users.id
 user.name
 user.color
```

With the code above, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Common (color) is not associated to User!
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

Associations

```
Model: User
    tableName: 'Users',
    classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
            User.hasMany(models.Common, {
                    as: 'common',
                    foreignKey: 'user_id'
                });
        }
})



Model: Common
tableName: 'Common',
classMethods: {
    associate: function (models) {
        AppCommon.belongsTo(models.User, {
            foreignKey: {
                name: 'user_id',
                allowedNull: false

            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: can you edit your question and add the association between your Models?

Comment: Updated.  Thanks.

Comment: that's way you get the error, you declared the association `User.hasMany(models.Common, { as: 'common', foreignKey: 'user_id'})`so when you make the include you have to called the same way `include: [{ model: db.Common,  as: 'common'}]`